# Accessing an API on an Android device over the Internet

Tags: android, cloud

I have a use-case for Android devices that I can't seem to wrap my head around. The gist of it is I want to be able to send an API command from my server to my Android app over the Internet. The solution already works if my server application is hosted on the LAN: each Android device has an IP, and I send the command to each device's IP. What if my server is on the cloud? Is there a way for my server application to connect to my Android device directly without the need for a local server?

In this use-case, the Android devices are connected to network through either WiFi or ethernet, and the network has internet access.

Any suggestion would be wonderful, thank you!

Comment: "Is there a way for my server application to connect to my Android device directly without the need for a local server?" -- send messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in local area network, both your server and client (Android device) are assigned with virtual IPs so there is no problem with see each other.

But when your move your server application to cloud, it cannot see your Android device anymore since your device is hidden by NAT. Only the gateway(your wifi router) IP can be seen by the server.

Some ways you can try:

1. Assign a static IP for your Android device, and configure your gateway to make a port forwarding to redirect the network traffic to your device. Then your server can see your device by sending to your-gateway-ip:port. But this is usually not a preferred way, unless you can always have full control of the client side network environment.
2. Change the application protocol to something like MQTT. In such case both your server and client can connect to this "broker" server so exchanging data is possible regardless of your client is under NAT or not. However, you may need to setup this extra broker server.
3. Find other third party notification services to do this server to client communication, such as Google Firebase.